# How to force Jmeter proxy server to listen only for specified page

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter proxy to record steps which i take in browser. Is there a possibility to set up proxy server just to listen for one specific page?

I want record only steps which are taken on www.test123.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Include pattern to restrict the requests that are recorded.

As per http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server

`The include and exclude patterns are treated as regular expressions (using Jakarta ORO). They will be matched against the host name, port (actual or implied) path and query (if any) of each browser request. If the URL you are browsing is
"http://jmeter.apache.org/jmeter/index.html?username=xxxx" ,
then the regular expression will be tested against the string:
"jmeter.apache.org:80/jmeter/index.html?username=xxxx" .
Thus, if you want to include all .html files, your regular expression might look like:
".*\.html(\?.*)?" - or ".*\.html" if you know that there is no query string or you only want html pages without query strings.`

"www.test123.com.*" should record requests only from the given URL.